# Trying to get data from another table, snapshot is null

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get data from another table using a cloud function and it's telling me the snapshot is null.

I have a Firebase database that I have some IoT devices connected to. They update their respective tables(I hope that's the right word) in the database (device_001, device_002, device_003) and send on to the external API I am using, that works which are great. 
Now I need to get the devices to look up where they are, I have set up another table which each contain their id, location, and timestamp.

Lookup table structure:

```
devices
    device_001
        id: ...
        location: ...
        timestamp: ...
```

Code:

```
exports.devices_Listener = functions.database.ref('/devices/{deviceId}/{entryId}').onWrite(snapshot => { 
    object = snapshot.after.val();
    getCurrentLocation();
    process();
    return null
})

function getCurrentLocation() {    functions.database.ref('locations/{deviceId}').limitToLast(1).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        var o = snapshot.val();
    })
}
```

I expected this to get the snapshot and allow me to get the location so I can store it with the processed data (that's all working so not included here).
When I try to get the location field I get can't read the property 'location'
and when I try to just log the snapshot to the console it tells me it is null.

I can't see what I've done wrong here but I'm sure it's small and simple.

Thanks for taking the time to read this nonsensical mess.